# Wordpress administration Over SSL - To Force SSL Logins and SSL Admin Access

Tags: admin, login, ssl

I have a plan to enable SSL to admin login of my wordpress site,

Is it a best practice?

What will be the behavior of plugins?

What are the pros and cons of my decision?

Answer (score 4):

Is it a best practice? Yes.

What will be the behavior of plugins? They should work fine.

What are the pros and cons of my decision? Pros: More secure. Cons: none.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: With a caveat: some plugins don't work fine over SSL in modern browsers, as they don't enqueue their scripts/css the "WordPress" way. Either of [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) or [SSL Insecure Content Fixer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) can fix many such problems.

Comment: I am not aware of any plugins that are popular and doing-it-wrong enough to break over SSL. Not saying they don't exist, but if you stick with tried-and-true plugins, you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a best practice? Yes, it is best practice to secure any area of the website where a user submits personal information.

What will be the behavior of plugins? If you're asking if plugins will recognize the admin area as well - Yes. If you're asking for a plugin that will accomplish your goals, I use - [WordPress HTTPS (SSL)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/). It also has the ability to allow you to secure individual pages and posts.

What are the pros and cons of my decision? Pros: More secure site. More comfortable users. Cons: None really, slight server load. Really, unnoticeable.